# Working and Explanation of LMTD in QlikSense

Tags: qliksense

I have visited Qlik Community website and tried to learn the concept of LMTD, but I am not able to understand fully. If someone can explain me fully with examples, working and flow of LMTD expression it would be highly beneficial for me and all others on StackOverFlow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.